# Override --warnaserror and -p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=True from a csproj

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a GH workflow that runs the `dotnet build` command line with `--warnaserror` `-p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=True`. This builds a solution.

The solution consists of multiple projects. Let's say `A.csproj` and `B.csproj`.

Is there any option to override the command line `--warnaserror` `-p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=True` from the `csproj` for a single project? I don't want to treat warnings as errors is project B.

I tried adding this to the `csproj`:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But it seems like it still prefers the command line settings, so the build still fails, because it still treats the warnings as errors in project B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property set on the command line is [Global](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022#global-properties) and can not be overriden. But project B can declare `TreatAsLocalProperty="TreatWarningsAsErrors"` and then the override should work.